# AngularJS not reading html tag in interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.7.9

In my database I have person name value stored as **`<i>FirstName</i> Last Name`**
When I use this value using interpolation as `{{person.name}}` I see it as  `<i>Alexandra</i> Golfi`

Why AngularJS can not read the html tag? is there a way I can still display first name in *italic style* while storing first name and last name in the same data base column

Thank you

Comment: not sure of my answer so I'm putting a comment but IIRC you need to use `{{person.name | html}}`

Comment: @jonatjano I tested it is coming as {{person.name | html}}

Comment: That is due to Angular Dom sanitizer, it sanitizer inputs and escapes html characters use the html pipe

Comment: @Ainz-sama which filter to use that reads <i> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-bind-html directive is a secure way of binding content to an HTML element.

When you are letting AngularJS write HTML in your application, you should check the HTML for dangerous code. By including the "angular-sanitize.js" module in your application you can do so by running the HTML code through the ngSanitize function.
syntax:

```
<element ng-bind-html="expression"></element>
```

Example :

```
<span ng-bind-html="person.name"></span>
```

Reference:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp